# Haddock on record fields Haskell

Tags: haskell, haddock

I am trying write haddock for record fields on an interface. Only some of the fields are exported so I only want some of them documented. I read the documentation page here: http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s02.html#id565178

However, I cannot seem to get this to work. Here is the section I am trying to write haddock for:

```
{-|
Describes a Clients connection and provides an interface for
storing data associated with the client. Each client will be given
a unique cid and are Eq if their cid's are Eq.

A ClientConn comes packaged with two functions for storing additional
information in Strings, lookup and modify. The lookup function
takes a key and returns the current value of the key or the empty
string if it has never been set. The modify function
takes a key and value and updates it such that the next call to
lookup with that key will return the value provided.
-}
data ClientConn = ClientConn { -- | The Unique ID for this client
                               cid       :: Integer,
                               -- | A lookup function for this client
                               lookup    :: (String -> IO String),
                               -- | A modify function for this client
                               modify    :: (String -> String -> IO ()),
                               chandle   :: Handle,
                               host      :: Net.HostName,
                               pid       :: Net.PortNumber,
                               msgList  :: List String,
                               dead      :: MVar Bool,
                               timestamp :: TimeStamp,
                               tid       :: MVar (ThreadId, ThreadId),
                               lock      :: MVar Lock.Lock}
```

The comment for the data type shows up correctly in the generated haddock. However, none of the records are generated. I would like it to generate for the cid, lookup, and modify records.

Thanks in advance!

The full source can be found here: https://github.com/jcollard/simple-server/blob/master/Network/SimpleServer.hs

Comment: I've run into various bugs with haddock'ing records before that were almost always worked around by adding newlines before the haddock comment. Does that work here?

Comment: I added a new line before each haddock comment with no change to the generated output. I've also tried it with {-| -}.

Comment: What does your module's export line say?

Comment: The module does export ClientConn(cid, lookup, modify).

Comment: You can see the full source here: https://github.com/jcollard/simple-server/blob/master/Network/SimpleServer.hs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, haddock doesn't currently support showing the documentation for only a few of a record's fields *as fields of that record*. You can work around this either by exporting all fields:

```
module Foo (ClientConn(..)) where ...
```

or by exporting the fields, but not as fields:

```
module Foo (ClientConn, cid, lookup, modify) where ...
```

In the latter case, the documentation will not automatically indicate that these functions are actually fields, but they will be usable in record syntax.

Comment: Good to know. For now, I will export them separately and not as fields.